# How to solve Discrete Combination problem?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

Translated from a native language to english.

A factory produces an item whose defect rate is 0.03 (meaning it's not defective 0.97 of the time).
Taking a sample of 500 items, what is the chance of finding 30 or more defective items?

Given directly from a teacher in a College Statistics class.

I can see that p=0.03 and q=0.97 have calculated that $P(x)= (0.03)^x*(0.97)^{500-x}$.I guess I could brute-force it by calculating $1-P(1)+P(2)+...+P(30)$ but that solution doesn't seem elegant. I don't understand what path I can take here. I don't think i can apply this to any formula like hypergeometric distribution or binomial distribution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number $X$ of defective items with defect rate $0.03$ is binomial-distributed, i.e. $X\sim \mathrm{Binom}(n=500,p=0.03)$. The probability in the question is $$\sum \limits_{x=30}^{500}{500\choose x}0.03^x 0.97^{500-x},$$ which is equal to the easier to compute $$1-\sum \limits_{x=0}^{29}{500\choose x}0.03^x 0.97^{500-x}.$$ To go on from here, I suggest you use a calculator, open up the binomial cumulative probability table.

Answer (score 0):

$P(x)$ has the form $P(x)=c r^x$ for some constants $c$ and $r$ I let you determine.
Now $\sum_{k=1}^{30}P(k)$ is a sum of consecutive terms of a geometric sequence. Can you take it from here ?

Answer (score 0):

You also need to subtract $P(0)$, and you need to remove the $P(30)$ term, but otherwise your solution is correct. You are correct in your suspicion that there is no simple expression for the final answer.

However, the problem might be asking you to do a normal approximation (instead of obtaining the exact probability). You will find that $30$ is about $4$ standard deviations above the mean of $15$ defective items, so there is virtually zero chance of seeing more than $30$ defective items.

Answer (score 0):

The situation you described is exactly descriped by a binomial distribution:

Insert $\textbf{P}(X\geq 30)=1-\textbf{P}(X<30)=1-\sum^{29}_{k=0}\binom{500} k p^k(1-p)^{500-k}.$

I don't think there is an easy way out for an exact solution. You can argue that $p$ is small and $n$ is large (allthough none of them is really as large/small as they should be) and use a poisson-approximation.